# USB transferspeed drops

Tags: windows-10, usb, ssd, usb-flash-drive, data-transfer

I'm copying a few large files (60GB) to a USB [flash drive](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/usb-flash-drives/usb-3-1-flash-drive-duo-plus-128gb-muf-128db-am/#:%7E:text=Fast.&text=%C2%B2Up%20to%20400MB%2Fs%20for,200MB%2Fs%20for%2032GB%20model.) (formatted as NTFS, selected better peformance in device manager for this flashdrive).

It is inserted into my PC's front I/O (USB 3.0, and also plugged in the appropiate header on the motherboard).
The files are stored on a Sata SSD (Samsung 860 1TB). The PC is idling so the nothing else is using the SSD or flash drive. The first, I'm guessing here, 20GB's were transferred at a speed of 60MB/s, after that it slowed down to about 4.5MB/s. I've read about RAM being used as cache, for to supply that information I have 32GB's of DDR4 (3600MHz, CL17)

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?
I don't see any bottlenecks here.

Thank you for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a flash drive starts with high speed and then goes down this is nothing unusual and in most cases has nothing to do with your PC. That your PC works correctly is shown by the good speed at the beginning.

There are multiple reasons for that behavior:

1. The internal cache of fast flash cells (SLC) is full and the other MLC/TLC/QLC cells are much slower
2. The flash controller chip on the stick is getting too hot and has throttled it's speed (especially for small-sized/tiny sticks heat is a massive problem)

The only way to fix this problem is using a constantly fast USB stick instead. Carefully read reviews to find out which sticks are fast and cheap.